# %timeit output differs depending on the environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, timeit

When I run in Google [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) the magic command `%timeit` (IPython 5.5.0) I get different output than when I run it on my PC (using IPython 7.7.0)

I run the following in both Colab and IPython:

```py
import numpy as np

%timeit np.mean([1,2,3])
```

w/ **IPython 7.7.0** I get the mean and std like:

```
8.83 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But in Colab w/ **IPython 5.5.0** I get:

```
100000 loops, best of 5: 9.13 µs per loop
```

Although the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) states that it is preferable not to take statistics, how can I get in Colab the mean and std like the former output?

Comment: Colab is running an old version of IPython, currently 5.5.0. (This is *not* the Python version, and not 3.6.9 or 3.7.2. IPython is a separate thing with a separate version.) IPython 5.5.0 predates the change to mean/stddev display, as well as the change to 7 default repeats.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I didn't know versions are independent. I will try if I can update the IPython version in Colab. Thanks